# Hot to use arbitrary color values for each side of the border property in tailwind-css?

Tags: css, next.js, tailwind-css

I'm trying to create a triangle using tailwind, here's the original code for [Triangle Generator](http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/).
to set colors for each side of the border I'm using `border-b-color` syntax which works fine but as long as I use the colors that are already defined in the theme, when I try using the `border-b-[#fff]` syntax to enter arbitrary values, it won't work.

here's the full code:

```html
<!-- this does not work -->
<div class="absolute z-1 -right-[1px] -bottom-[1px] w-0 h-0  border-solid border-t-0 border-r-0 border-b-[4em] border-l-[4em] border-t-transparent border-r-transparent border-l-transparent border-b-[#1D1F2D]"></div>

<!-- this works fine -->
<div class="absolute z-1 -right-[1px] -bottom-[1px] w-0 h-0  border-solid border-t-0 border-r-0 border-b-[4em] border-l-[4em] border-t-transparent border-r-transparent border-l-transparent border-b-primaryColor"></div>
```

any idea how to get around this using tailwind?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to do as following: `border-b border-[#color]`

I mean, in my case border-b-[#000] will not work as well. So, I usually specify border color separately like above.

**UPDATE**:
You can refer to this [link](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/pull/560#issuecomment-503222143)

Comment: thank you for very quick response, in my case it turned out it was not a problem with tailwind, I'm trying to dynamically add classes using classNames and it seems that tailwind will not create the proper classes in this way.